# Emgu: Setting up CUDA with C#

Tags: c#, opencv, cuda, emgucv

I am building an application which compares the timescale of computing sets of 1,000, 10,000 and 100,000 frames from a webcam using CPU and GPU approaches.

So far I have written the CPU implementation but I now need to integrate my GPU algorithm into my project.

I chose Emgu after doing research and finding it allows support for Open-CV and CUDA with C#. However I am now facing the problem that VS2012 is not noticing my `__global__` calls in my program.

Below are the namespaces I am using:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.GPU;

using DirectShowLib;
```

And I have successfully linked to what I think are all of the applicable libraries to get CUDA working with Emgu:

[image]

With this in mind, what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've edited your question and removed asking for tutorials/offsite resources as these make your question off-topic. As a general guide, present your problem, show what you've done, and give what you'd expect as a result. [See here on more about asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry shoe,  I should know better.  Writing questions at 2am isn't the best idea

Comment: Do you have a actual problem to describe? You haven't told us what  the problem is, so it's pretty difficult to tell you what's wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like this *might* be an incorrect version of EMGU, most of the EMGU problems I have encountered are due to incorrect versions.

I had to use version 2.4.9 to get GPU up and running nicely.

This can be downloaded at the following link:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/emgucv/files/emgucv/2.4.9-alpha/

I am using the 2.4.9 version DLL's found with this download.

Hope this helps!

Good luck

**EDIT**

Snippet that may be useful

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Parallel.For(0, facesDetected.Length, i =>
            {
                try
                {
                // Code in here
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Strange part is, that's the library I am using... I really have no idea why this won't work.

Comment: Ah if you are using the EMGU version 2.4.9 that might explain it.
The DLL's you have in the screenshot are version 2.9.0, might be a conflict between DLL versions

Comment: Am I linking to all the required libs? If so,  should I be able to write kernels in the main program body? Or is there a special syntax

Comment: I think you are using the correct libs, however for running emgu in paralell I did not use the normal CUDA syntax with calling kernel (as I think that is C++ only?)

I used the following 

                Parallel.For(0, facesDetected.Length, i =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Code here
                    }
                    Catch{}
};

Comment: Ahh I see, could you possibly edit your answer and post a snippet? That sounds like it might work for me :)

Comment: Sorted, let me know if its any use to you :)

Comment: Heading in for my back to back end of term exams, will let you know when I get home.   Thanks for all your help man :)

Comment: Np,
Good luck with exams